# Customizing CSS in MDwiki

Tags: markdown

I have been using MDwiki for a project with pretty good results.  But I haven't found a way to add my own custom CSS that applies to the whole project.

Currently my workaround is to just been include a `<link .. >` tag in every `md` file but that is a bit tiresome and lame.  Like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/custom.css"></style>
```

Is there a better way of doing this short of hacking into MDWiki itself?   The documentation mentions theming but not this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your HTML into the `navigation.md` file which is included on all pages.